# component Rendering blank HTML

Tags: angular

```
 import { homeModule } from './home.module';
 console.log("Inside Home Module");
 const welcomeComponent = {
  template: 'Hello',
  };
 console.log(homeModule.component('welcome', welcomeComponent));
 homeModule.component('welcome', welcomeComponent);
```

Not showing anything  after running ... getting blank page .Any Solution?

here is  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hcjwe6)

Comment: Do you mind creating a demo on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @ShashankVivek ADDED